# How to get the Peso sign (₱) in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols, unicode

I'm looking for a way to include a Philippine Peso sign (Unicode code point 0x20B1) in a LaTeX document.  Using the textcomp package (as shipped with the base latex distribution) in conjunction with times, I get like this:

[image: picture of \textpeso]

when what I want is this:

## ₱

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This assumes that the arc of the P is half the height of the letter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\PHP}{%
  \begingroup
  \leavevmode\,\vphantom{P}%
  \dimen\z@=.5\fontcharht\font`P\relax
  \dimen\tw@=0.33333\dimen\z@
  \ooalign{%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\dimen\z@+2\dimen\tw@-0.4pt}{\rule{\fontcharwd\font`P}{0.4pt}}\cr
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\dimen\z@+\dimen\tw@-0.2pt}{\rule{\fontcharwd\font`P}{0.4pt}}\cr
    P\cr
  }%
  \,\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\PHP\quad\textbf{\PHP}\quad{\Large\PHP}

100\PHP

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like the fact that this answer has fewer dependencies, and seems to scale nicely.

Answer (score 7):

If one needs the ability to adjust the vertical space between the cross-lines, then this can work:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\pesos{%
  \stackengine{-1.38ex}{P}{\stackengine{-1.2ex}{$-$}{$-$}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}
\begin{document}
35\pesos ~\sffamily 35\pesos ~\ttfamily 35\pesos
\end{document}
```

[image]

If using a `\scriptstyle=` sign is sufficient, a nested stack is avoided, at the expense of a `\scalebox`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\newcommand\pesos{\stackengine{-.85ex}{P}{\scalebox{1.15}[1]{$\scriptstyle=$}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}
\begin{document}
35\pesos ~\sffamily 35\pesos ~\ttfamily 35\pesos
\end{document}
```

[image]